# What's the difference between Tobi's transportation jutsu and the teleportation jutsu used by the Fourth Hokage?

Tags: naruto

In Naruto Shippuden, Minato Namikaze, the Fourth Hokage, used the teleportation technique (Hiraishin no Jutsu) . Tobi on the other hand uses the transportation technique (Kamui).

How are the transportation jutsu and the teleportation jutsu different since both involve displacing stuff to other locations?

Comment: What jutsus are you referring to? There are so many different types of space related techniques XD

Comment: You'll need to be more specific than that. Please include Japanese names, full English names or links in your question, to allow us and figuring out exactly what techniques you're referring to. I've put the question on hold until you [edit] to improve it. Good luck, and enjoy the site! :)

Comment: @Madara Uchiha: I believed the "naruto" tag would be sufficient. My bad! Is the edit more clear now?

Comment: @John: There are many transportation and teleportation techniques in Naruto. I already know you're talking about Naruto, but what techniques in particular? :)

Comment: @Madara Uchiha: Well that's something I didn't knew. I thought there were two types only, transportation and teleportation. So I guess I'm interested in the techniques of Tobi and the 4th Hokage in particular.

Comment: @John Within transportation and teleportation, there is a plethora of jutsus, not only two. Off the top of my head, I can think of body flicker (high speed movement), thunder god (teleport to mark), kamui, and reverse summoning.

Comment: It's clear that he is talking about Minatos Flying Thunder God, and Obitos Kamui. I don't understand what was unclear?

Comment: @TechSupport It was only clear after the edits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you are referring to Obito's Kamui and Minato's Flying Thunder God.

The basics of both Jutsu's is kind of similar. In both the Jutsu, the user can transport himself from one place to another (normally known as teleportation).

Let's begin with Minato's Jutsu. According to [Flying Thunder God Technique](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Flying_Thunder_God_Technique) article on the wiki:

> The Flying Thunder God Technique is a technique created by the Second
>   Hokage, Tobirama Senju, which allows the user to transport themselves
>   to a given marked location instantaneously. To activate this technique,
>   the user places a special seal or "technique formula" (術式,
>   jutsu-shiki) to mark an intended destination. After this is done, they
>   can enter a dimensional void at will that instantaneously transports
>   them to the location of the seal.

Now we come to Obito's Jutsu. According to [Kamui](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kamui) article on the wiki:

> Kamui allows the user to transfer anything to another dimension. Once
>   a target is sent to this dimension, it is unable to escape. This
>   technique, when used through Obito's right eye, is also able to make
>   the user "intangible" by transporting portions of their body to the
>   same pocket dimension.

Differences:

- Kamui doesn't need any Mark or special seal for it to work.
- Kamui can only be performed if the user is using MangeKyou Sharingan,
  whereas Flying Thunder God doesn't need Mangekyou Sharingan.
- Kamui creates space in different dimensions where the user can
  transfer objects or himself and can stay in that dimension for
  as much time as the user wants to, but in Minato's technique, the
  user is immediately transported to a marked location.