# Are the Space-Time Barrier and Flying Thunder God Technique similar to one another?

Tags: naruto

I came across the difference between the [**Flying Thunder God Technique**](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Flying_Thunder_God_Technique) and Obito's [**Kamui**](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kamui) Technique Transportation Technique, [here](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/6320/whats-the-difference-between-tobis-transportation-jutsu-and-the-teleportation).

But what I am struck with the fact that Fourth Hokage used a Space-Time Barrier tecnique to teleport Nine-Tail's [Tailed Beast Ball](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Tailed_Beast_Ball). So my questions are:

- Is Space-Time Barrier similar to Flying Thunder God Technique?
- Is it used to transport things using Teleportation Technique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a) Jikukan kekkai similar to Flying Thunder God Technique?

Yes, it is derived from "Flying Thunder God Technique", [Space–Time Barrier](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Space%E2%80%93Time_Barrier).

---

> b) Is it used to transport things using Teleportation Technique?

This barrier technique incorporates the use of the "Flying Thunder God" formula as well as a unique set of hand seals to erect a barrier capable of warping away **anything which comes in contact with it.**